# Rendering shadow sprites in cocos2d-x

Tags: sprites, cocos2d, shadows

I am writing a 2D game with cocos2d-x. I want to put a "shadow" sprite on a background sprite using the equation:

> MAX(0, Cd * 1 - Cs * S)

where `Cd` is the destination color (that is, a background pixel), `Cs` is the source color (the shadow pixel), and `S` is the scale factor (between 0 and 1).
The `MAX()` function is used to avoid negative results. This is a lighting effect: when the shadow sprite pixel is 0, there is no effect on the background
pixel, otherwise, the background pixel becomes darker.

Now, the only way that comes to my mind is to change the blending equation to `GL_FUNC_SUBTRACT`, but it doesn't compile with cocos2d-x (can't found it).

I would subclass the `CCSprite` class in order to implement the `draw()` method in order to change, when needed, the blending equation, call the original `draw()` method and restore the blending equation to its previous state at the end of the method.

So my questions are two:

1. How to use `glBlendEquation()` with cocos2d-x? Keep in mind that I am writing a game for iPhone/Android/Windows.
2. Are shadows handled this way in 2D games?

Comment: as a side note: as stated in cocos2d-x site, it's not recommended to develop a game for windows using it, unless you are rewriting all opengles functions used in cocos2d-x to use OpenGL/DirectX!

Answer (score 1):

cocos2d is not much different than a normal opengl app. there are some basic states that is set while you are running a cocos2d app, but other than that every thing is just the same as a normal opengl application. I guess the normal way of using `glBlendEquation` or `glBlendFunc` is to inherit some class from `CCSprite` class (or any other class that you want it to drop shadow) and then override `draw` method. it will look something like this :

```
-(void) draw
{
    // create a backup from glBlendEquation
    // do somthing with glBlendEquation
    [super draw];
    // restore glBlendEquation options
}
```

I'm not familiar with either obj-c nor opengl (I'm using cocos2d-x in c++ and occasionally needed to add some basic opengl function), but from what I know the code above should work.

Comment: Gajet, i am using cocos2d-x, exactly like you. Your solution is exactly equal to the one i had tought about using. It should work, but the glBlendEquation() function does not belong to standard opengl (it seems to me)...

Comment: For standard i mean the functions you get including "gl/gl.h".

Comment: cocos2d-x is using OpenGL-es, which shares many features with OpenGL. after a search it seems OpenGLes2 has a function named glBlendEquation (http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendEquation.xml) but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: With cococ2d-x, i tried the function glBlendEquationOES(), using GL_FUNC_REVERSE_SUBTRACT_OES as parameter. This is because the first frame i draw is the background, the second is a shadow. I want to subtract, from the background, the shadow sprite, so i have to use a reverse subtract blending function. The sad thing is that it compiles, run but doens't do what i want. Damn

Comment: Finally i made it work: i had to change the blending factors (DST=GL_ONE, SRC=GL_SRC_ALPHA)!!! You can esily control the opacity in the usual way (setOpacity().

Comment: @lukeluke can you maybe post this solution in a separate answer and accept it? That way, readers will find the solution immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

You can use shaders if you want to go for *glBlendEquation*. Have a look here;

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/10862/how-to-create-cool-effects-with-custom-shaders-in-opengl-es-2-0-and-cocos2d-2-x and
- http://smashriot.com/cocos2d-v2-0-and-shaders/

Please note that, using more amount of shaders can effect the performance of some devices.

Answer 2:

And if light direction is constant in your game, than you can attach shadow with graphics only (i.e in PNG only). Or you can use separate dark shadow image with some transparency. There are the lightweight solutions.